# No hover on next li-element

Tags: jquery, hover, gallery, zooming

I try to do a image gallery with a simple zoom effect, but i just get a hover effect every second element. any suggestions would be great.

here is the css:

```
ul{
    margin: 140px 0 0 140px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.item_resized{
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -43px;
    margin-top: -43px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

the html:

```
<ul class="imgGallery">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

and jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imgGallery').find('li').each(function() {   
        $(this).hover(function() {                                              
            /* Add Img-Container */
            $(this).prepend('<div class="item_resized"></div>');
        },function() {
            /* Remove Img-Container */
            $(this).find('.item_resized').remove(); 
        });
    });
});
```

as you can see, the li-element 2 and 4 is not affected by the hover effect.

thanks!

danny

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/BLJae/ working fine?

Comment: This is fine in Chrome and FF [look](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/6gJ9F/). Which browser are you having problems with?

Comment: start by replacing $('.imgGallery').find('li') by  $('.imgGallery li')

Comment: no need for the `each` loop either... just bind the `hover` straight to the selector.

Comment: @Niklas It's not working when selecting jQuery 1.6 or 1.5.2. http://jsfiddle.net/BLJae/3/ 1.4.4 is working oO

Comment: @Niklas this is just working in ie but not in chrome or firefox
but see below for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imgGallery').delegate('li', 'mouseover',function() {   
            /* Add Img-Container */
            $(this).prepend('<div class="item_resized"></div>');
        }).delegate('li', 'mouseout',function() {
            /* Remove Img-Container */
            $(this).find('.item_resized').remove(); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I had to change the events to: mouseenter and mouseleave but it works like a charm! Thank you very much ShankarSangoli!

Answer (score 0):

try to hover `only` 2'nd element of each `ul`

```
<script>$("ul li:nth-child(2)").hover(function(){...});</script>
```

please look on [jQuery:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

for every 2'nd element use `:nth-child(odd)`